# Add a Linq clause to a Iqueryable object

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a method who get a Iqueryable object get from a LINQ Query
On this object, i want to add a LINQ clause : .skip(20)
How can i do that from my method ?

Thanks by advance

Comment: with code. What have you tried? what does your method look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't "add" a clause to an *existing* query, because the queries themselves are immutable - but you can create a *new* query which is the existing one but with an extra clause:

```
IQueryable<Foo> newQuery = oldQuery.Skip(20);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = FunctionThatReturnsIQueryable().Skip(20);
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as you haven't enumerated over the query, you can always add clauses. The clauses are only executed as soon as you get the results (e.g. with `for each`).
You could do something like `GetSomeIQueryable().Skip(20)`. That returns you a new query that includes your skip clause.